# onChange event won't fire in .map function React

Tags: reactjs, events, drop-down-menu, onchange, array.prototype.map

I cannot get this onChange event to fire? The goal is to render multiple options from a drop down, from some data I have, then console log "hello" when any of the options is clicked...

It doesn't seem to want to let me use onChange or onClick events in my rendered option elements. If i can simply console log first , then i can figure out everything else. I only posted the necessary code but I can post the rest if needed!

```
const SlideData = [
  {
    title: "Slide 0",
  },
  {
    title: "Slide 1",
  },
  {
    title: "Slide 2",
  },
];

export default SlideData;
```

```
let options = SlideData.map((item, index) => (
    <option
      key={index}
      value={index}
      onChange={() => {
        console.log("hello");
      }}
    >
      {item.title}
    </option>
  ));
```

```
 <select className={styles.select} onChange={goto}>
          <option>--Select--</option>
          {options}
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goal was to pass the index and console log it technically. so I guess this worked for me

```
const slideRef = useRef();
const goto = ({ target }) => {
    slideRef.current.goTo(parseInt(target.value, 10));
    console.log(target.value);
  };

  const options = SlideData.map((item, index) => (
    <option key={index} value={index}>
      {item.title}
    </option>
  ));

return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Slide ref={slideRef} {...properties}>
        <div className={styles.slide}>First Slide</div>
        <div className={styles.slide}>Second Slide</div>
        <div className={styles.slide}>Third Slide</div>
        <div className={styles.slide}>Fourth Slide</div>
        <div className={styles.slide}>Fifth Slide</div>
      </Slide>
      <div>
        <Button type="button" onClick={back}>
          Back
        </Button>
        <Button type="button" onClick={next}>
          Next
        </Button>
        <select className={styles.select} onChange={goto}>
          <option>--Select--</option>
          {options}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

`option` tag doesn't support `onChange`. You can use `onClick` instead.

```
onClick={() => {
  console.log("hello");
}}
```

Comment: thank you but my inspector doesnt seem to console log with that either?

Comment: I wonder if I need to create an Option component and pass the data to it...

Comment: I think you should handle in function `goto`

Comment: yeah maybe i have to call another function outside of it

Comment: I don't really understand it, but i guess that works. Im guessing a react thing ... thank you